Square taper with 15.5mm end?
I got a Star Trac NXT for £15 for some indoor fitness but it's missing its left crank arm. I thought to myself oh I'll just throw on a standard steel crank arm and I'll be good to go BUT it doesn't seem to fit. I'm starting to think they have made a proprietary square taper because I can't seem to find any information on a square taper standard that is 15.5mm flat to flat. (Normal square taper is around 12.5, I believe.)
Now if I have to bin the thing its not a big loss to me but I really want to save it... just not by shelling out £120+ on a whole crank set.
